# Angular Material md-select don't show value on prepopulate

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular4-forms

I have a nested form, a group inside of a group:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
        ...
        placeFirst: this.formBuilder.group({valy: ['', Validators.required]}),
        ...
    })
```

When I want to update the form with prepopulated data:

`this.listingForm.get('placeFirst.valy').setValue(listing.placeFirst);`

The form is prepopulated because I can see the field filled with the json pipe, but the md-select does not show the title. The HTML is:

```
<div formGroupName="placeFirst">
  <md-select placeholder="Place" formControlName="valy" (change)="creator.placeFirstSelected($event.value)">
    <md-option *ngFor="let placeFirst of creator.placesFirst" [value]="placeFirst">
      {{placeFirst.title}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
</div>
```

If I use 'select' and 'option' instead of 'md-select' and 'md-option', I can see the title of the current option selected.

Comment: Be sure to check if the option in `creator.placesFirst` is really equal to `listing.placeFirst`.

Comment: Thank you, but listing.placeFirst is the value I want to set (one), creator.placesFirst is the list of values to choose (several). The actual [value] of the select form is already set (as I can see using {{ listingForm.value | json }}), but md-select does not update the option title to the one already set in the form. If I don't use material, it works

Comment: Well.. I think you didn't got what I meant... In a nutshell, to bind the correct value in `md-select` you must set the exact object.. that's why you should check if `listing.placeFirst` is really equal to any option in `creator.placesFirst`.

Comment: Ops sorry. No, I set the value from the data I get from Firebase, so it's same value but it does not come from the same list. So I would have to iterate the list and choose the value?

Comment: Probably yes, until [**this issue**](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2785) is closed (there's an open PR).

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves the question, If you want to answer it I'll set it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @developer033 said in the comments, the issue is that the object marked as selected and the object from the list are not equal. As the issue is still opened ([github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2785)), my workaround for now is just filtering the list with the keys:

```
    const placeFirst = this.placesFirst.filter(el => el.key === placeFirstKey)[0];
    this.listingForm.get('placeFirst.valy').setValue(placeFirst);
```